# Firebase and Swift How to pull specific record by child value?

Tags: swift, firebase, swiftui

I'm using Firebase with swift (SwiftUI to be exact) and since my DB contains many records (more than 10k records) I'm trying only pull the relevant data from the DB (Otherwise it will pull ALL the data every time which will be a waste).

I think that I should use .indexOn but I don't really know what to do (I don't have much experience with json).

This is the code in SWIFT that I tried using:

```
ref.child("Items").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        for child in snapshot.children {
            let snap = child as! DataSnapshot
            // Doing stuff here.
        }
})
```

This is my data structure:

```
tbl (the actual table):
    items:
          ____:
               serial:
               date:
               more parameters...:
          ____:
              serial:
              date:
```

and so on...

The blank spots (___:) represents names which were auto generated by Firebase (just random numbers from 0 to the amount of records in the table), and I want to pull by a query the specific record that contains a matching serial.

This is how my rules in Firebase DB looks like:

```
{
   "rules": {
   ".read": true,
   ".write": false
   }
}
```

How should I use .indexOn on my Firebase rules?
Or is there any other alternative to get what I want?

Thanks in advance.

Update:

I'm trying to get a specific record out of the query. Based on the data structure I specified above, what I'm trying to get is the serial and the date of the child that have a serial number matching to a serial number which I'll input to the query.

Suppose I want to use X8M9320C in the query.
What I would like to get is the serial (X8M9320C) and the date back from the table.

Also, the naming for the ___: is an auto generated numbers which are automatically initialized when I upload the json file to Firebase.

Update 2:
[image: DB structure]
The image above represents how the db structure looks.

After some debugging, I saw that after running the query, I'm getting 0 values from the row:

```
let childSnaps = snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot]
```

The full code:

```
let serial = "XCM8320CMW"
    let myDataRef = self.ref.child("tbl")
    let itemsRef = myDataRef.child("items")
    let query = itemsRef.queryOrdered(byChild: "serial").queryEqual(toValue: serial)
    query.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
        let childSnaps = snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot]
        guard let firstChild = childSnaps.first else {return}
        let date = firstChild.childSnapshot(forPath: "date").value as? String ?? "No Date"
        print(date)
    })
```

Comment: .indexOn has nothing to do with this task. You are looking to [Query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/lists-of-data#filtering_data) for a specific child node (or nodes). We need more info but to clarify, the ___ should not be a random number as in ( 1, 2 , 3) etc - it's probably a key generated with .childByAutoId that looks like this `-JyisISkjmosis89`. If not, we need to know what it is. We also need to know what specifially you are querying for - what do you want to get back out of the database. Please update the question with more details and we'll take a look.

Comment: The key is auto generated once I upload it to FireBase. it's literally a number representing an index I think from the original json file.
I just updated the question

Comment: Please provide complete code in your question - a one-liner doesn't help us as the failure is in the code before that. And, by the way. If you are querying for the string `X8M9320C` then you will have no matches because that string doesn't exist. Howerver the string `_____X8M9320C_____ ` does - I am using ____ to indicate blank spaces since comments don't support those.

Comment: Updated again :)

Comment: Right. Please see my above comment as `let serial = "XCM8320CMW"` will return no results because that string doesn't exist in your database.

Comment: Ok, well then what do you suggest I do?
Do you have any idea how I can search for that?

Comment: The simple solution is to remove all the white space before saving so it's a string of  `X8M9320C` is stored in Firebase instead of a string with a bunch of spaces before and after the string. Then that query will work perfectly.

Comment: I think that the image may have mistaken you. I just edited it quickly to hide the actual serial number since I'm not allowed to publish it. There aren't any actual white spaces between the serial code in the DB to the left " or to the right ". The string is stored as the serial code itself (I only understood what you meant after the update of your response). If you have any idea what else might have gone wrong I will highly appreciate it. Thanks a lot anyways for the attempt to help!

Comment: I understand but your screen shot is showing a string in the database which doesn't match your search string, therefore it's not found. Note that your code is searching for `serial` wheras your database is showing `Serial` (capital). That's probably the issue but if not, update your screenshot and code in the question and we'll take another look as the code works as long as the database has a lower case `s`erial, or your change your query to query on node `S`erial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL;DR

There was a coding issue which I addressed below and also the string the OP is searching for is this

```
X8M9320C
```

but what's stored in Firebase is this

[image]

Noting all of the white space (space bar characters) before and after the stored string. The two are not equal which is why my query below won't work on it.

--
Longer answer:

To clarify, Firebase does not have tables; it has key: value pairs which are also called parent and child *nodes* where the parent is the key and the child is a value, which can also be a pair of key: values.

This sounds like a basic Firebase query which is covered [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/lists-of-data#sorting_and_filtering_data) in the documentation.

Given a structure like the one in your question:

```
my_data
   items
      item_0
         serial: "OU812"
         date: "20200427"
         more parameters...:
      item_1
         serial: "X8M9320C"
         date: "20200513"
         more parameters...:
```

Here's the query which will query for serial of X8M9320C and print the date from that node. Keeping in mind that a query could return multiple results we need to iterate over all the returned nodes.

```
func queryForItem() {
    let serial = "X8M9320C"
    let myDataRef = self.ref.child("my_data")
    let itemsRef = myDataRef.child("items")
    let query = itemsRef.queryOrdered(byChild: "serial").queryEqual(toValue: serial)
    query.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
        let childSnaps = snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot]
        for snap in childSnaps {
            let date = snap.childSnapshot(forPath: "date").value as? String ?? "No Date"
            print("serial: \(serial) has a date of \(date)")
        }
    })
}
```

and the output

```
serial: X8M9320C has a date of 20200513
```

If you know there will only ever be nothing returned or one returned node (if the serials are guaranteed to be unique for example) you could eliminate the for loop and do this

```
let childSnaps = snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot]
guard let firstChild = childSnaps.first else {return}
let date = firstChild.childSnapshot(forPath: "date").value as? String ?? "No Date"
print(date)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it isn't working for me.
I keep getting the following error:
"Using an unspecified index. Your data will be downloaded and filtered on the client. Consider adding ".indexOn": "Serial" at /my_data/Items to your security rules for better performance"

I tried to implement the code you posted in both ways, and both failed. Either way, the 2nd way matches my needs, since a serial should be unique.

Do you know what should I do in order to fix the error I'm getting? Thanks!

Comment: @RnadomG That's not an error. It's a reminder to increase performance use ".indexOn" but it's not a requirement and will not prevent the code from working. I pulled that code from a working project and as shown in the answer, the output to console is what's expected. Please troubleshoot your code as 'failed' doesn't really give us much to go on. To do that, add a breakpoint in the code and run it. Then step through line by line examining the vars until it does something unexpected. Once you find that, update the question with complete and minimal current code and indicate what line failed.

Comment: Hi again and thanks for the answer, after some quick debugging I think that I found the source of the problem, I updated the question accordingly